# Deflate Compression Specification

Tags: zip, compression, deflate

I'm currently looking through the DEFLATE compression specification and am confused about [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1951#page-13) part:

```
               0 - 15: Represent code lengths of 0 - 15
                   16: Copy the previous code length 3 - 6 times.
                       The next 2 bits indicate repeat length
                             (0 = 3, ... , 3 = 6)
                          Example:  Codes 8, 16 (+2 bits 11),
                                    16 (+2 bits 10) will expand to
                                    12 code lengths of 8 (1 + 6 + 5)
                   17: Repeat a code length of 0 for 3 - 10 times.
                       (3 bits of length)
                   18: Repeat a code length of 0 for 11 - 138 times
                       (7 bits of length)
```

If I'm understanding correctly, `0-15` are the lengths of the Huffman codes for the code length sequences. However, I do not understand what `16-18` is supposed to be. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 16-18 codes are instructions to the decoder to generate several lengths, either zeros or the repeats of the last length.

So for example:

```
18(12) 14 4 3 3 3 4 4 5 17(3) 5 16(9) 7
```

becomes:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 4 3 3 3 4 4 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7
```

where the numbers in parentheses are coded as 7, 3, and 2 bits respectively immediately after the Huffman code for that symbol.